# Getting LUIS DateTime Entity into FormFlow

Tags: c#, datetime, botframework, azure-language-understanding, formflow

I have a chatbot in C# that takes the users message, and using LUIS decides what intent the user has. When a specific intent is found it starts a FormFlow. I have been able to successfully fill fields in the form from the users initial message using LUIS entities. However I am stuck on the Date and Time entity. When LUIS provides the entities it sends them as 2 separate entities (builtin.datetime.time & builtin.datetime.time), yet I need these saved under one Form Field (DateTime). **How can I have the entity Time AND Date get saved to the DateTime field?**

I currently only know how to save only one field (save time and defaults to today's date, or save date and defaults to 12AM).

Here is how I currently save the date entity to my Form field

```
        EntityRecommendation entityDateTime;
        result.TryFindEntity("builtin.datetime.date", out entityDateTime);
        if (entityDateTime != null)
            entities.Add(new EntityRecommendation(type: "DateTime") { Entity = entityDateTime.Entity });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Chronic Parser** (it's being used in some of the examples in official botbuilder github source code)

URL: https://github.com/robertwilczynski/nChronic

To **merge date and time** into one single datetime entity, see the sample code below

```
EntityRecommendation time;
EntityRecommendation date;

var timeFound = result.TryFindEntity(EntityConstant.EntityBuiltInTime, out time);
if (result.TryFindEntity(EntityConstant.EntityBuiltInDate, out date))
{
    return timeFound ? (date.Entity + " " + time.Entity).Parse() : date.Entity.Parse();
}
```

**ChronicParserExtension.cs**

```
public static Tuple<DateTime, DateTime> Parse(this string input)
{
    var parser = new Parser(new Options
    {
        FirstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday
    });

    var span = parser.Parse(input);

    if (span.Start != null && span.End != null)
    {
        return Tuple.Create(span.Start.Value, span.End.Value);        
    }

    return null;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It couldn't find a definition for Parse, should I be using a specific directive?

Comment: Did you add `nChronic` to your project? and you need to check the import too

Comment: I was thinking BotBuilder V3.0 template already had Chronic included in the project

Comment: @Wolfer: I just want to confirm, please try `var test = new Chronic.Parser().Parse("test");` to see if you have  any compilation error.

Comment: @Wolfer: did you add in the **ChronicParserExtension** class?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I actually did not have to include Chronic Parser functionality, as the datetime that my LUIS app provides is being entered into a Form that has DateTime parsing functionality already built into it

Comment: How to do this in NodeJS?

Comment: @KosalaNuwanPerera I'm not sure if nodejs have `Chronic`

Answer (score 0):

Much thanks to @kienct89, as he helped me figure things out, however I did not need to use Chronic.
I got the results I wanted with the following code, happy to field comments if there is a better way to write this

```
        EntityRecommendation entityDate;
        EntityRecommendation entityTime;
        result.TryFindEntity("builtin.datetime.date", out entityDate);
        result.TryFindEntity("builtin.datetime.time", out entityTime);
        if ((entityDate != null) & (entityTime != null))
            entities.Add(new EntityRecommendation(type: "DateTime") { Entity = entityDate.Entity + " " + entityTime.Entity });

        else if (entityDate != null)
            entities.Add(new EntityRecommendation(type: "DateTime") { Entity = entityDate.Entity });

        else if (entityTime != null)
            entities.Add(new EntityRecommendation(type: "DateTime") { Entity = entityTime.Entity });
```